# String to date exception on certain computer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

i coded a check to make sure user entered date in dd/MM/yyyy format. However, it did not work on certain computers, the exception is thrown. However, it worked well while running on my computer. Why is that? am i doing it wrong or there is some settings that i need to do on the computer.

```
  Try
     checkDate = "24/02/2013"
     selectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(checkDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

  Catch ex As Exception
     lblError.Text = "Invalid Date."

  End Try
```

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: Since it only occurs on certain computers, the problem is probably caused by different cultures. If you look at the MSDN documentation, you see that they use "d" as format in the example code to parse the date.

Comment: @Hanno The culture, in theory, should not be an issue, since the culture and format are being explicitly specified.

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments.

how do i change the culture? i set the regional and language settings to be the same as my computer's but it still doesn't work.

i need to go back to the computer to see what exception was printed.

but its so strange, my friend's and my computer works well, but the desktop that we're deploying the application to doesn't seem to allow us to parse it in dd/MM/yyyy.

is there any other methods to check if the date entered is in dd/MM/yyyy format?

Comment: @StevenDoggart I know, but it is suspicious and I don't see any other potential problems.  @ user2107475 What happens if you check a date such as "01/01/2013"? (where switching day/month will not be an issue)

Comment: @Hanno I agree, it's very curious.  The culture does seem like the most likely culpit, but that doesn't make sense.  That's why I asked what the actual exception message was.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I will find out the exception once i get my hands on the computer.

Comment: @Hanno will try your suggestion and let u know.

Comment: This now shows you why not to just set a label to "Invalid date" when you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatProvider (the 3° argument of ParseExact) should match with the format that you are using, and this could be false in your case. InvariantCulture is not a "fit-all" culture; it's a culture that does not change and you can rely on it when you are persinting/retrieving datetime without showing them to the user.
I think (I can't try it now) that you should do something like this:

```
 checkDate = "24/02/2013"
 Dim dtfi As New DateTimeFormatInfo()
 dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
 selectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(checkDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", dtfi)
```

Answer (score 0):

using this in your page_load might work..

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
```

of course change en-US depending on your culture preferences

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats wrong, i re-upload the application and the error is gone. strange.